# Can PXE boot of Hyper-V VMs be disabled?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, boot, windows-server-2012-r2, pxe-boot

Hyper-V virtual machines have the ability to PXE boot.  Obviously, PXE boot [raises some security concerns](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64915/what-are-the-biggest-security-concerns-on-pxe).  The problem is, unlike a typical physical machine's firmware, there isn't an obvious way to disable PXE boot altogether.

Hyper-V manager shows each of the VM's network adapters in `Settings=>Firmware=>Boot Order`:

[image]

You can move a network adapter to the bottom of the boot order, but you can't remove it altogether from that screen.  So if, for some reason, Hyper-V can't boot from any of the other drives, the VM still tries to PXE boot and shows this screen:

[image]

I've scoured `Settings=>Network Adapter` for a way to disable PXE boot to no avail.

So my questions are:

1. How do you disable PXE boot in a Hyper-V VM?
2. If you can't disable PXE boot, is there a good reason why?

---

*I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2*

Comment: Regarding your concerns about PXE > The implementation of PXE in a corporate environment may raise
> concerns about security. This document shows why these concerns are
> mostly unfounded. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21247020

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Use Powershell to Remove Network Boot Devices from the Boot Order

You can use PowerShell to strip the `Network` `BootType`s from the VMs boot order.

#### Extract the Current Boot Order

Using Powershell you can use this command to extract the current boot order:

```
$old_boot_order = Get-VMFirmware -VMName testvm -ComputerName MyHyperVHost `
                  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BootOrder
```

If you inspect `$old_boot_order` You should see the list of boot devices for `testvm`.  Something like this:

[image]

#### Strip the Network Boot Devices

You can strip the boot devices from the boot list with the `Network` `BootType` using this command:

```
$new_boot_order = $old_boot_order | Where-Object { $_.BootType -ne "Network" }
```

Inspecting `$new_boot_order` should look something like this with no more `Network` boot devices:

[image]

#### Set the New Boot Order

To set the new boot order for the VM use this command:

```
Set-VMFirmware -VMName testvm -ComputerName MyHyperVHost -BootOrder $new_boot_order
```

#### Confirm the New Boot Order

To confirm what you did use that first `Get-VMFirmware` command again:

```
Get-VMFirmware -VMName testvm -ComputerName MyHyperVHost `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty BootOrder
```

---

*Beware: If you use both PowerShell and Hyper-V manager to make changes to the boot order, PowerShell may report erroneous (out-of-date) boot order.  See also [this technet thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4fcce488-e4f4-41c2-9d15-1eedc89a6f68/why-dont-the-boot-orders-in-powershell-and-hyperv-manager-match).*

Comment: What do you do if `Get-VMFirmware : The Generation 1 virtual machine or snapshot "ubuntu504" does not support the VMFirmware cmdlets`

Comment: @nelaaro I know I'm 2 years late, but I've added an answer for the likes of you and me that still use Gen1

Answer (score 0):

In case someone lands here looking for **Generation 1 VM** solution, I ended up looking for it all around the place.

Found it was really simple, in MS official docs:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/set-vmbios?view=win10-ps

```
Set-VMBios TestVM -StartupOrder @("Floppy", "LegacyNetworkAdapter", "CD", "IDE")
```

> This example configures virtual machine TestVM to check for a boot device in the following order: floppy disk, network, CD drive, hard disk.

The `Set-VMBios` supports `-VMName <name of VM>` as well, I use that for readability, while MS docs obviously uses shorter form.

Comment: I like that, but get an error on a gen1 VM. Invalid Parameter (0x80041008) FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.Se
   tVMBios

Comment: Hm, didn't see anything like that. Which OS version do you use? And which Powershell version? Also, make sure to have Hyper-V management installed. By the looks of it it seems as if your device doesn't  recognize command. (I will assume you did not copy paste error, as there is a space mid command)

Comment: This change the boot order, but doesn't disable network boot.

Comment: That's copy of example from official documentation. Just add/remove and sort to your needs. Docs don't say that any member is required. Did you try : Set-VMBios TestVM -StartupOrder @("CD", "IDE")

Answer (score 0):

Those firmware entries you mention are of type Firmware Application (101fffff). They can be controlled from within the guest OS using bcdedit, the hypervisor will replicate changes:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc749510(v=ws.10)

Host:

```
get-vmfirmware six

VMName SecureBoot SecureBootTemplate PreferredNetworkBootProtocol BootOrder
------ ---------- ------------------ ---------------------------- ---------
Six    Off        MicrosoftWindows   IPv4                         {File, Drive, Network}
```

Guest:

```
bcdedit /enum all /v

Firmwareanwendung (101fffff)
----------------------------
Bezeichner              {e56c0c0b-9e14-11eb-8bb5-00155d001627}
description             EFI Network

bcdedit /delete {e56c0c0b-9e14-11eb-8bb5-00155d001627}
```

The entry has been removed from the Hyper firmware page (if the settings are currently open, hit the refresh button on the firmware page)

```
get-vmfirmware six

VMName SecureBoot SecureBootTemplate PreferredNetworkBootProtocol BootOrder
------ ---------- ------------------ ---------------------------- ---------
Six    Off        MicrosoftWindows   IPv4                         {File, Drive} <<< no network
```

But what if we remove the harddisk?

```
Firmwareanwendung (101fffff)
----------------------------
Bezeichner              {e56c0c0c-9e14-11eb-8bb5-00155d001627}
description             EFI SCSI Device

bcdedit /delete {e56c0c0c-9e14-11eb-8bb5-00155d001627}
```

Congratulations, you just killed your machine. There's no option on the Hyper-v Gui page to fix this, nor will a guest reboot fix this, so thank you for providing a powershell command to fix this, I just tested, it's working. In the Hyper GUI, there's a stupid way to fix the firmware by opening the harddisk page, changing SCSI number, clicking "Apply", then changing it back, hitting "apply" again. There's MS for you.

What happens on a real computer when a firmware application is removed through bcdedit? Will the motherboard (or whereever that mysterious NVRAM resides) re-create the firmware entry after a reboot? Will it be then picked up by bcd store automatically?